# WSO2 ESB xpath problems

Tags: xpath, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I want to use the following xpath

> /Users/User/UserID

This does not work because the ESB adds a soap envelope and body around my xml, what is the correct xpath to use or how can I remove the soap envelope and body?

The xml is:

> 

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <Users xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
         <User>
            <UserID>a</UserID>
            <Username>a</Username>
            <Email>a</Email>
            <Password>a</Password>
         </User>
         <User>
            <UserID>a</UserID>
            <Username>a</Username>
            <Email>a</Email>
            <Password>a</Password>
         </User>
         <User>
            <UserID>a</UserID>
            <Username>a</Username>
            <Email>a</Email>
            <Password>a</Password>
         </User>
      </Users>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

EDIT:

This works when I try to log it outside of my iterate mediator

```
//*[local-name() = 'Users']/*[local-name() = 'User']/*[local-name() = 'UserID']
```

but when I try to log it inside the iterate mediator it returns nothing?

Comment: //Users/User/UserID does not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working by using the following

```
<property xmlns:int="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" name="uri.var.ID" expression="$body/int:User/int:UserID/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Comment: 'int' will likely be the namespace provided by data services. i.e. `xmlns:int="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"`. You can add namespaces in the UI when defining your property, they're often needed in WSO2 for XPATH expressions to work properly.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer.

Answer (score 0):

To access your elements you should go through envelope and body. 
Here is an example with switch mediator:

```
<switch xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" 
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:int="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" 
        source="boolean(/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/int:Users/int:User/int:UserID/text() = 'string_to_compare'">
  <case regex="true">
     ....
  </case>
  <default/>
</switch>
```

UPD
corrected XPath expression

Comment: Using the following returns nothing
<log level="custom">            <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" name="test" expression="/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/Users/User/UserID"/>
            </log>

Comment: It seems I missed to add namespace of Users node. Just updated the answer, can you try it?

Comment: That still returns nothing

Comment: Can you try "/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/int:Users/int:User/int:UserID" ?

Comment: I tried that and that also doesn't work, I found this online and this seems to work //*[local-name() = 'UserID'] , will using this cause any problems though?

Comment: This will match UserID node in amy namespace anywhere in the document. So it looks a bit risky. But you can try to construct the whole chain with wildcarded namespaces: /*[local-name() = 'Envelope']/*[local-name() = 'Body']/*[local-name() = 'Users']/*[local-name() = 'User']/*[local-name() = 'UserID']

Comment: I'd say that probably your example XML was not completely correct, some nodes holding a different namespace or whatsoever. Because /soap:Envelope/soap:Body/int:Users/int:User/int:UserID must match nodes from your example.

Comment: Using /*[local-name() = 'Envelope']/*[local-name() = 'Body']/*[local-name() = 'Users']/*[local-name() = 'User']/*[local-name() = 'UserID'] again returns nothing, the xml I posted in my question is what gets returned if I log just "/"

Comment: Using this //*[local-name() = 'Users']/*[local-name() = 'User']/*[local-name() = 'UserID'] I'm able to get the result back, also using that I can use the iterate mediator to iterate over each value. My problem now is if I try to log that inside the iterate mediator it returns nothing?

Comment: I have now got this working using the following
<property name="uri.var.ID" expression="$body/int:User/int:UserID/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<property name="yourParamName" expression="$body/Users/User/UserID" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

You can read more on the predefined Synapse XPath variables [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB460/Synapse+XPath+Variables).

Comment: $body gives me the body and its contents, but adding /Users or anything else after it returns nothing